# How to copy spreadsheet's URL reference to a tracking sheet in a different google spreadsheet after its been automatically created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code automatically creates a user-specific google sheet when a new entry on a row is added. I want it to then copy and paste the URL of this new sheet into a tracking sheet within a different google sheet

I've tried opening the sheet and copying the link, and just getting the URL and copying. It does log the URL to the lgoger, but no idea how to get it to log it on the actual sheet

```
 function createNewSS() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');
    var row = ss.getLastRow();
    var name = sourceSheet.getRange(row,4).getValue ()
    var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
    var insertLink = ssNew.getUrl()

 Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
function createNewSS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');
var row = ss.getLastRow();
var name = sourceSheet.getRange(row,4).getValue ();
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getUrl();
sourceSheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(ssNew);
```